# How to setup for each loop in Kotlin to avoid out of bounds exception

Tags: kotlin

In java I got this construction

```
for (let i = 0; i < x.length-1; I++
```

And here to avoid `outOfBoundsException` we are using `x.length-1` but how to do the same thing in Kotlin? I got this code so far

```
x.forEachIndexed { index, _ ->
    output.add((x[index+1]-x[index])*10)
}
```

And it crashes on the last element when we call `x[index+1]` so I need to handle the last element somehow

Input list

```
var x = doubleArrayOf(0.0, 0.23, 0.46, 0.69, 0.92, 1.15, 1.38, 1.61)
```

Comment: Can you post a sample for the input list _x_?

Comment: @lukas.j added the array that I am modifying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a classic Java for loop you got two options in Kotlin.

One would be something like this.

```
val x = listOf(1,2,3,4)

for (i in 0 .. x.lastIndex){
    // ...
}
```

Using `..` you basically go from 0 up to ( and including) the number coresponding to the second item, in this case the last index of the list.( so from `0 <= i <= x.lastIndex`)

The second option is using `until`

```
val x = listOf(1,2,3,4)

for (i in 0 until x.size){
    // ...
}
```

This is similar to the previous approach, except the fact that `until` is not inclusive with the last element.(so from `0 <= i < x.size` ).

What you probably need is something like this

```
val x = listOf(1,2,3,4)

for (i in 0 .. x.lastIndex -1){
    // ...
}
```

or alternative, using `until`, like this

```
val x = listOf(1,2,3,4)

for (i in 0 until x.size-1){
    // ...
}
```

This should probably avoid the IndexOut of bounds error, since you go just until the second to last item index.

Feel free to ask more if something is not clear.

This is also a great read if you want to learn more about ranges. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ranges.html#progression

Comment: perfect. That `until` range is what I was looking for

Comment: @BobRedity Glad i could help. When in doubt always go to the Kotlin documentation, it is very useful and well written.

Comment: IMO, better than either of these options is `for (i in x.indices)`

Comment: @Tenfour04 True, it's another valid approach and easier to use, but i wanted to be as close to the classic java loop he described as i could.

Comment: Oh, I missed that OP is sampling one past i in the loop.

Comment: Technically, there's a third option: you can use an old-fashioned `while` loop, exactly as you would in Java. But of course that's long-winded and error-prone (and requires the loop variable to be defined in the outer scope)… Which is why you hardly ever see that in Kotlin!

Answer (score 6):

You already have an answer, but this is another option. If you would use a normal list, you would have access to `zipWithNext()`, and then you don't need to worry about any index, and you can just do:

```
list.zipWithNext { current, next ->
    output.add((next - current)*10)
}
```

---

As mentioned by k314159, we can also do `asList()` to have direct access to `zipWithNext` and other list methods, without many drawbacks.

```
array.asList().zipWithNext { current, next ->
    output.add(next - current)
}
```

Comment: Upvoted both because functional operators for the win

Comment: Use `asList()` instead of `toList()`; then you won't be duplicating the array.

Comment: @k314159 the [docs state](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-list.html): `Returns a List that wraps the original array.`. Doesn't that meant that the original array doesn't go anywhere, isn't the memory usage still doubled?

Comment: No, the list that you get from `asList()` is just a view into the original array. Thus, if you do this: `val a = arrayOf(1,2); val l = a.asList(); a[0] = 3; println(l);` you will get `[3,2]` because the list is just a view into the array. If you use `toList()` instead, the list will remain `[1,2]` because it's a copy of the original values of the array.

Comment: I know that `asList` keeps a reference of the array and `toList` makes a copy. But I don't see how that automatically implies that the data is not duplicated. I mean we know it is a reference to the array, but is it in itself a list of references to the same data the array contains? Or just a new list with a wrapper that does the same action on both the array and the list? I'm not saying you are wrong, I do believe that you are right, but I just can't find any doc info to state one or the other.

Comment: You can see its implementation at https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/ea836fd46a1fef07d77c96f9d7e8d7807f793453/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/generated/_ArraysJvm.kt#L167 - it's very simple, and you can see that it doesn't create any copies of anything. All calls to `get()`, `size` etc. act directly on the original array.

Comment: @k314159 nice, thank you. I've edited the answer to include this.